# How to install an Email Share Button in Blogger?

Tags: html, blogger

I have installed custom share buttons below my blog posts and I'm very content with them, they work perfectly. I now want to install an email share button beside my already existing share buttons.
By an email share button I mean I want my readers to be able to click the email share icon and they be directed to a page where they can email the blog post title and URL to any recipient of their choice.

I've tried using the below code, which I typed below `<data:post.body/>`:

```
<a class='email' expr:href='&quot;mailto:url=&quot; + data:post.url + &quot;&amp;title=&quot; + data:post.title' rel='nofollow' target='_blank' title='Share Via Email'><img alt='Share Via Email' border='0' height='30px' width='30px' src='http://i1379.photobucket.com/albums/ah140/mynamesiram/Mobile%20Uploads/6FE18FCC-506A-4D2A-A87A-846EB42B33B8_zps09g4dxpt.jpg'/></a>
```

However this code didn't work the way I wanted it to. The link does direct the reader to a separate page, which displays an email 'form', but the URL for the blog post appears in the 'mail to' part of the form instead of in the actual body of the email. Ideally I'd like the 'mail to' option empty for the reader to insert a relevant email, and the subject line with the blog post title and the URL of the blog post in the body of the email.

My blog's URL is as follows: http://www.blankesque.com

Answer (score 0):

So you want to use 
`Post Title` as `Mail Subject` and 
`Post url` as `Mail body`

In that case use the code below

```
<a expr:href='&quot;mailto:?subject=&quot; + data:post.title + &quot;&amp;body=&quot; + data:post.url' rel='nofollow' title='Share Via Email'><img alt='Share Via Email' border='0' height='30px' width='30px' src='http://i1379.photobucket.com/albums/ah140/mynamesiram/Mobile%20Uploads/45AA973D-D8A1-4FAE-A31A-138DA7CB8443_zpsteklwczz.jpg'/></a>
```

please let me know if this is what you wanted.